# arabic numbers in textbox with internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, localization, internationalization

I'm working to translate an web application into Arabic. Running the app on a Windows box with Arabic installed in Internet Explorer, I get the Eastern Arabic (indic) numerals (١٢٣) instead of 0, 1, 2, 3 in the text boxes.

How can I have Internet Explorer show me these as 0, 1, 2, 3...? Is there a vendor specific CSS property I could set?

Chrome and Firefox do not have this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some fonts have an alternative stylistic set using western numerals, but I highly doubt it.  Still, it might be worth exploring this font-face sandbox -- you might find something that works for you :

http://clagnut.com/sandbox/css3/

The other option is Javascript.  Here's an example :

http://jsfiddle.net/five23/txAL8/

```
<div class="content">١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩١٠</div>

var text = $(".content").text()
    .replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g, function (char) {
        return char.charCodeAt(0) - 1632;
    })
    .replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, function (char) {
        return char.charCodeAt(0) - 1776;
    });

$(".content").html(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by changing the font name,

In my case I want to display the same character to all users

you can choose a font that contains Arabic-Hndi digits and import it using the css ( @font-face  ) then simply use it,

This works fine for all major browsers (IE .. Firefox .. Chrome)

[Look at this smaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsptB.png)

here is the full code of the page:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

@font-face {
    font-family: ArabicTwo_Bold;
    src: url( ArabicTwo_Bold.eot);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: ArabicTwo_Bold;
    src: url( ArabicTwo_Bold.ttf);
}


div , input {
 font-family: ArabicTwo_Bold;
}
</style>


<input type='text' value='هذا نص هندي 123456 ' />
<div> هذا نص هندي 123456  </div>
</body>
</html>
```